# Is it possible to convert the Datetime.Now to Tamil Unicode character in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, unicode

I'm wondering if .NET allow multilanguage support for Datetime?

I'm trying to convert the Datetime.Now value to equal Tamil Unicode character.

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar, perhaps provide sample input and output?

Comment: For example I'm able to convert a DateTime into a string "Wednesday, February 16 2011 at 4:16 PM" but I want the same thing in Tamil eg: "புதன்கிழமை, 16 பெப்ரவரி 2011, 04:16 PM".

Answer (score 1):

```
CultureInfo taIN = new CultureInfo("ta-IN");
var dateTimeString = DateTime.Now.ToString(taIN);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime` data type stores its information in binary. To convert it to a string, use the `ToString` method.

This should convert it to a string in the current culture. If that culture is set to produce Tamil date formats, then it will be in Tamil.

Answer (score 0):

If the Tamil culture was installed/availible, you could simply call, for instance,

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyddMM", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("si-LK","si-LK")); // Sri-Lankan culture info
```